# How to make a text animate (brighter, darker, brighter....) in ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, animation, video, text, ffmpeg

I know how to draw a text:

```
ffmpeg -i my.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=some_font.ttf: text='some text': fontcolor=white: fontsize=28: [omitted]" -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

How can I draw a text which shines or animates? Meaning, it slowly becomes brighter, then darker, then brighter again and so on.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: See the 2nd to last example at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Examples-50